# Replace text not contained in a tag using either Regex or XmlParser

Tags: c#, regex, html-parsing, xml-parsing, regex-negation

I know that using Regular expressions to parse or manipulate HTML/XML is a bad idea and I usually would never do it. But considering it because of lack of alternatives.

I need to replace text inside a string that is not already part of a  tag (ideally a span tag with specific id) using C#.

For example, Lets say I want to replace all instaces of ABC in the following text that are not inside a span with Alternate text (another span in my case)

`ABC at start of line or ABC here must be replaced but, <span id="__publishingReusableFragment" >ABC inside span must not be replaced with anything. Another ABC here </span> this ABC must also be replaced`

I tried using regex with both look ahead and look behind assertion. Various combinations along the lines of

```
string regexPattern = "(?<!id=\"__publishingReusableFragment\").*?" + stringToMatch + ".*?(?!span)";
```

but gave up on that.

I tried loading it into an XElement and trying to create a writer from there and getting text not inside of a  node. But couldn't figure that out either.

```
XElement xel = XElement.Parse("<payload>" + inputString + @"</payload>");
XmlWriter requiredWriter = xel.CreateWriter();
```

I am hoping somehow to use the writer to get the strings that are not part of a node and replacing them.

Basically I am open to any suggestions/solutions to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, 
    @"(?<!              # assert that we can't match the following 
                        # before the current position: 
                        # An opening span tag with specified id
     <\s*span\s*id=""__publishingReusableFragment""\s*>
     (?:                # if it is not followed by...
      (?!<\s*/\s*span)  # a closing span tag
      .                 # at any position between the opening tag
     )*                 # and our text
    )                   # End of lookbehind assertion
    ABC                 # Match ABC", 
    "XYZ", RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```

will work with all the caveats about HTML parsing (that you seem to know, so I won't repeat them here) still valid.

The regex matches `ABC` if it's not preceded by an opening `<span id=__publishingReusableFragment">` tag  and if there is no closing `<span>` tag between the two. It will obviously fail if there can be nested `<span>` tags.

Comment: Looks good. But what about if had some extra attributes in the span tag eg: ... <span class="my class" id="__publishingReusableFragment" style="my style" >... I tried replace the span part of the regex as follows <\s*span.*?id=""__publishingReusableFragment"".*?> But now it doesn't match after the end of the span tag - ... </span> this ABC...

Comment: You're starting to run into all the reasons why parsing HTML with regexes isn't a good idea. If your attributes never contain a `>`, you can use `<\s*span[^>]*id=""__publishingReusableFragment""[^>]*>` and hope for the best.

Comment: Yup, that was it, thanks. Yeah, which is why I was hoping walking it with LinqToXML or a good LinqToHtml lib might be an idea. This is just a throw away, one off importing tool, that needs to munge some data on the way in to cut down on manual post processing.

Answer (score 2):

I know its slightly ugly, but this will work

```
var s =
    @"ABC at start of line or ABC here must be replaced but, <span id=""__publishingReusableFragment"" >ABC inside span must not be replaced with anything. Another ABC here </span> this ABC must also be replaced";
var newS = string.Join("</span>",s.Split(new[] {"</span>"}, StringSplitOptions.None)
    .Select(t =>
        {
            var bits = t.Split(new[] {"<span"}, StringSplitOptions.None);
            bits[0] = bits[0].Replace("ABC","DEF");
            return string.Join("<span", bits);
        }));
```

Comment: Not ugly at all. This is a great way of doing what needs to be done (which is a bit ugly). The only problem is that it ignores all spans. not just spans with a particular id, like the regex. This probably could have been expanded to suit me though and would help in a lot of other situations.